# Retweeting with Tweepy and Python. Keep getting Error

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am just trying to retweet tweets that I've found via search and I keep getting the following error: 
TweepError: [{u'message': u'Sorry, that page does not exist', u'code': 34}]

Here is the main function:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
      twitter = TwitterAPI()
      results = twitter.search("cool")
      print results[0].id

      for i in xrange(0,10): 
         try:
            twitter.retweet(results[i].id)
         except tweepy.error.TweepError:
            print "failure"
            pass
```

Here are my retweet and search functions:

```
def search(self, string):
      results = self.api.search(string, "en", "en")
      return results

def retweet(self, tweet_id):
      self.api.retweet(id)
```

Anyone know why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. I threw out my retweet function and instead just did this:

```
results[0].retweet()
```